# C# Indexer and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, indexer

I have a property in a class:

```
public int this[int index]
        {
            get { return _desk[index]; }
            set { _desk[index] = value; }
        }
```

But I cant use this class in Linq. How to make it ?

Comment: Please give an example of what you're trying to do. Your question is unclear.

Comment: How do you want to use it? What do you mean with "I can't use this"? If the indexer is the only way to access your data then you may consider to implement IEnumerable<int>

Comment: What do you mean "I can't use this class"? We can see neither a class nor how you are trying to use it.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to understand this question ?

Comment: var position = new Position(); var count = position.Count()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your class doesn't implement [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) but has an indexer and a *Count* property, you can create an IEnumerable of indexes using the [Enumerable.Range Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx), and project each index to the collection item using the [Enumerable.Select Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891):

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, obj.Count)
                      .Select(index => obj[index])
                      ...
```

Comment: +1, this is a viable alternative to implementing `IEnumerable<..>` (especially if the class isn't under your control), I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: +1 Very nice solution! I guess people always need "ready to use" code even when you need a glass ball to guess their intent...

Answer (score 3):

An indexer doesn't automatically give you enumeration. In order to be able to call LINQ methods, you need to implement [`IEnumerable<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) on your class.

I'm assuming your `_desk` object is a simple array - if I'm wrong here and `_desk` is something other class that has an indexer, you may need to make that class implement `IEnumerable<int>` too.

You'd then need to do something like this:

```
public class Position : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private int[] _desk;

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { return _desk[index]; }
        set { _desk[index] = value; }
    }

    /* the rest of your class */

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<int>)_desk).GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _desk.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I've no idea if the implementations of `GetEnumerator()` are best practice when wrapping an array, but they should work.